# IE6 CSS Debugging?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

Is there a good way to debug CSS in Internet Explorer 6?

Or at least any help like the Microsoft Script Debugger for Javascript?

Comment: I was always using background: red, background: yellow, background: green etc and was checking where the error is.. :) have fun with IE6 ! Welcome to 2012 :)

Comment: I also use borders on all my div's while I work out what IE is doing. Or maybe you just ignore IE6 now - even Microsoft baked a cake at for the death of it.

Comment: Borders and colors is the usual way, I debug CSS, but I am looking for something nicer, if this is possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) and [MS Web Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18359) are both very useful.

Comment: I can't get Firebug Lite working, but MS Web Developer Toolbar seems to be more than I ever expected!

Comment: Yeah, it's not bad is it! I was surprised as well - seems a little known secret.

Answer (score 1):

I always use [IE Developer toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18359). Just install it, run ie6 and go `view->explorer bar->ie developer toolbar`.